# every point in $\mathbb{N}$ are isolated point, How?

Tags: general-topology

I just started to learn about topology in $\mathbb{R}$ and my professor started with talking about interior, isolated, accumulation, and boundary points.

One thing I didn't quite understand was that 'there is no interior point in $\mathbb{N}$, but every point in $\mathbb{N}$ are isolated points.' At first, I thought this has something to do with countability, that we know $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ are countable sets where $\mathbb{R}$ is not.

> In example given in class,
>
> 1. interior point doesnt exist in $\mathbb{N}$,$\mathbb{Q}$ where every pt is interior point in $\mathbb{R}$
> 2. every pt is isolated point in $\mathbb{N}$, where isolated pts dont exist in $\mathbb{R}$

can someone explain why??

Comment: What topology are you using on $\mathbb N$?  If you're talking about the inherited topology from real space, it turns into the discrete topology, so every point is its own neighborhood

Comment: With your phrasing of "no interior point ..., but every point...are[sic] isolated," it sounds like you're thinking of these as opposite conditions. Depending on the topology, a point can be both isolated and interior, isolated and not interior, interior and not isolated, or not isolated and not interior. These are not mutually exclusive conditions (again, depending on the topology).

Comment: all of this was based on topology of real numbers, I didnt even know there are different types of topology out there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you say that you've "just started to learn about topology in $\mathbb{R}$," I'm going to assume that we're using the *standard topology* on $\mathbb{R}$ and that we're discussing $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, rather than topological spaces in there own right. With that said, we need definitions:

- $x \in S$ is an interior point (of $S$) if there exists open set $U \ni x$ such that $U \subset S$. For the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, this means that there needs to be a small open interval $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ that is a subset of $S$.
- $x \in S$ is an isolated point (of $S$) if there exists open set $U \ni x$ such that $U \cap S = \{x\}$. For the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, this means that there is a small open interval $(x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ such that $x$ is the only element of $(x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon) \cap S$.

Let's talk interior points first:

- Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(x-1, x+1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ so $x$ is an interior point.
- Let $x \in \mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$. No matter how small $\epsilon > 0$ is chosen, we can't fit the interval $(x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ into $\mathbb{N}$ (there will always be points outside of $\mathbb{N}$ contained in this interval). Therefore, there are no interior points in $\mathbb{N}$.
- Let $x \in \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$. For any $\epsilon >0$, we have that $(x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon) \cap\mathbb{Q}^C \neq \emptyset$, i.e., there's no way to fit an open interval around $x$ that doesn't contain an irrational number. Therefore, there are no interior points in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Moving on to isolated points:

- Let $x \in \mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $x$ is the only element of $(x-1/2, x+1/2) \cap \mathbb{N}$ so $x$ is isolated.
- Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. For any $\epsilon > 0$, the intersection $(x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon) \cap \mathbb{R} = (x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ contains elements besides $x$ (infinitely many of them, in fact). Therefore $x$ is not isolated.
- Let $x=p/q \in \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$. For any $\epsilon >0$, the intersection $(x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ contains points besides $x=p/q$. This is since we can always find an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{2^n} < \epsilon$ and therefore the rational number $\frac{p}{q} + \frac{1}{2^n}$ is also in $(p/q - \epsilon, p/q + \epsilon)$. Therefore there are no isolated points in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome! Just wait until you start learning about topologies in general =) At that point, we're no longer stuck with the restriction that open sets have to be of the form $(a,b)$--we get define what we mean by an open set (within reason, the open sets must still satisfy a couple axioms). This is where there are a couple other mentions of "the discrete topology" or "the subspace topology" in other replies--these are alternative ways of defining what is meant by "an open set". See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Topology if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

So take any point $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then take the neighborhood $N_{1/2}(n)$. This contains no other point in $\mathbb{N}$. Thus, $n$ is isolated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your metric is the standard Euclidean metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Take any natural number $x\in\mathbb{N}$. The open ball centered at $x$ with radius of $\epsilon$ is the set $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. No matter how you choose $\epsilon$, the set will inevitably contain something that is not a natural number. This is a fact, although not obvious. Similar reasoning goes for $\mathbb{Q}$.

A point is called an isolated point of set $E$ if it's not a limit point of $E$. Consider some natural number $x\in\mathbb{N}$. It suffices to find *one* neighborhood of $x$ such that it contains no point in $\mathbb{N}$ other than $x$ it self. Take $(x-\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2})$.